# For-loop type - can't recognise it

Tags: java, for-loop

In Robert Sedgewick's book i found the following code:

```
public class  QuickF{
 public static void main(String[] args){

    int N = 20;
    int id[] = new int[N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        id[i] = i;
    }
    for( In.init(); !In.empty(); ){
        int p = In.getInt(), q = In.getInt();
        int t = id[p];
        if (t==id[q]) continue;
        for (int i =0; i<N; i++){
            if (id[i] == t) id[i] = id[q];
        }
        Out.println(" " +p+""+q);
    }
  }
}
```

My question is about this line: `for( In.init(); !In.empty(); )`. What type of forr loop is this? Is this syntacticaly legal? If yes, what is the documentation of this for loop type?

Comment: `for(x; y; z)` is the form you're familiar with, but you can omit any of `x`, `y` or `z` if it's not necessary

Comment: It's just a regular for loop. It doesn't matter what you write in the statements (except for the middle one), they can even be empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a basic `for` loop.

It is documented in the **Java Language Specification**, section [14.14.1. The basic for Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.1):

```
BasicForStatement:
  for ( [ForInit] ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate] ) Statement

ForInit:
  StatementExpressionList
  LocalVariableDeclaration

ForUpdate:
  StatementExpressionList

StatementExpressionList:
  StatementExpression {, StatementExpression}
```

Normally, you'll see it like this:

```java
ForInit:      int i = 0   // LocalVariableDeclaration
Expression:   i < 10
ForUpdate:    i++         // StatementExpression
```

```java
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) {
    // code
}

// mostly the same as:
int i = 0;
while ( i < 10 ) {
    // code
    i++;
}
```

<sup>*Mostly the same, since the scope of `i` is limited to the loop, and the `continue` statement will go to the `i++` statement, not directly back to the loop.*</sup>

But as you can see, all 3 are optional, where `ForInit` can be a statement list instead of a variable declaration, and `Expression` defaults to `true`.

```java
ForInit:      In.init()   // StatementExpression
Expression:   !In.empty()
ForUpdate:                // not present
```

```java
for ( In.init() ; !In.empty() ;  ) {
    // code
}

// same as:
In.init();
while ( !In.empty() ) {
    // code
}
```

The `Expression` defaulting to `true` means that the following are the same. I personally prefer the first, since `for (;;)` almost reads like "forever".

```java
for (;;) { // loop forever
    // code
}

while (true) { // loop forever
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a [regular for-loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

> The general form of the `for` statement can be expressed as follows:
>
> ```
> for (initialization; termination;
>      increment) {
>     statement(s)
> }
> ```

It is no different from `for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)`, except with a different *initialization* and *termination*, and without an *increment*.

You are allowed to omit the increment statement because

> The three expressions of the `for` loop are optional